# Express default (locals) variables removed when error

Tags: node.js, express

In Express Node.js app (generated by express-generator) you have this structure:

```
..bunch of not interesting code before...
//APP - DEFAULT TEMPLATE VARIABLES
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.user = req.user;
    res.locals.config = config;
    res.locals.language = req.headers["accept-language"];
    next();
});

//APP - ROUTES
...bunch of routes...

//APP - CATCH ERRORS
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.locals.error = {
        title: "Error " + (err.status || 500),
        code: err.status,
        message: req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : ""
    };
    res.locals.config = config;
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        layout: 'layouts/error'
    });
});
```

Why variable `res.locals.config` and `res.locals.user` is undefined when `APP - CATCH ERRORS` is fired?

Comment: What error? Maybe default middleware was not even executed.

Comment: Error happend inside routers (after default definitions)